# Unclear most vexing parse

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, default-constructor, most-vexing-parse

Let's assume the following class Foo.

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;
};
```

if I want to make an instance of this class and initialize it, I should do: `Foo foo1 = Foo();` to call the constructor.

```
int main(void)
{
    foo1 = Foo(); 
    cout << foo1.i << " : " << foo1.j << endl; // " 0 " 
}
```

then I thought I'd call the default constructor with the following line but it doesn't:

```
int main(void)
{
    Foo foo2(); // most vexing parse
    cout << foo2  << endl; // " 1 " ??? why?
    foo2.i++; // error: request for member ‘i’ in ‘foo2’, which is of non-class type ‘Foo()’ 
}
```

Why is foo2 initialized to int(1) and not Foo()?

I know about the most vexing parse, it tells that, from my understanding, when a line can be interpreted as a function, it is interpreted as a function.

But foo1() is interpreted as an int, not a function, nor a Foo class.

The line Foo foo2() compiles because it is interpreted as a function prototype. OK.

Why does this line compiles? `cout << foo2  << endl;`

Does it print the address of the foo2 function?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out which `operator<<` overload the compiler picked.

Comment: *if I want to make an instance of this class and initialize it, I should do: `Foo foo1 = Foo();` to call the constructor.* No, you should just do `Foo foo1;` or `Foo foo1 {};`, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Note that there is no "most vexing parse" here. The most vexing parse does involve the same rule about function declarations. Here is an example of the most vexing parse: `Foo foo2(int());` (rewrote my comment, since my original example wasn't quite complete)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, `Foo foo2();` is a function declaration. For `cout << foo2`, `foo2` would decay to function pointer, and then converts to `bool` implicitly. As a non-null function pointer, the converted result is `true`.

Without using `boolalpha`, the [`std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) would [output](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) `1` for `true`.

> If boolalpha == 0, then converts v to type int and performs integer output.

You can see it more clearer with usage of [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

```
cout << boolalpha << foo2  << endl;  // print out "true"
```